# How to visualize a vector field in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, animation-nodes

At the beginning of [this video](https://youtu.be/ewXkFohbN2s?si=lD1msmfFAvBLhSlK) you can see a math equation and vector arrows showing that force.

How can i achieve the same thing in Blender Geometry Nodes?

Can anyone guide me..

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: could you provide at least a formula you wanna see? sorry, but just providing a link with "i want that" might make people think you are looking for a dumb to make your work. So please show us a) what you have tried and provide that blend file and b) provide the formula by which the arrows should turn because we have no idea what force field you mean. thx for your understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Quite a flexible approach would be:

Create a *Volume Cube* covering the desired domain, convert it to a grid of points at the desired resolution, and instance an Arrow object on the points:

[image]

Orient your arrows in the direction of **(X',Y',Z') = f(XYZ)** (i.e. a function of the arrows' *Position*.) Scale as some function of the *Length* of **f(XYZ)**..

[image]

Here, the normalized length (min,max) -> (0,1) is stored as a factor for shading:

[image]

with this kind of result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you . Sorry if i sound rude but is there any way to make it animate as well . As it will help visualize better . Will be thankful if you share

Comment: Hi, mystery man .. that's not rude at all ...  What do you want to animate? if it's the flow of particles or somesuch along the directions indicated, then it's a simulation.. you would have to decide on a style of visualisation, I guess... I may have jumped with the edit of your title.. maybe you mean 'animate flow guided by a vector field'?

Comment: Yes sir that's what i am looking into. Will really appreciate if you make a animate flow guided vector field

Comment: I've checked out the (excellently  illustrative) animations in your reference, and they are carefully  selected illustrative examples, geometrically simple, no simulation required. The animators never actually drive the motion with the entire vector field. If you drive  _all_  arrow-instances with the field, I think the result might be quite visually confusing.. That might be better visualized with simpler, thin flow-line curve-segments moving through the volume ? Else, you could make  life easier by isolating specific features to animate, like them. The reference solution is _not_ general.

Comment: if possible just show me how to animate i want to visualize custom math equations to see how they look in 3D . Can you create any simple example with any math equation so that i can understand how to make on my own

Comment: @mysteryman happy to have a shot at it.. but will take a little while, and a style-guide would help, I think.

Comment: Please take your time . I will wait and thanks for helping